# ASP.NET and Google Oauth 2 stopped working

Tags: asp.net

We have suddenly been hit with an issue with our google third party logons. We can authenticate fine with Facebook and LinkedIn but Google fails with what looks like an IIS 404 Error.

The system uses the standard asp.net technique to login:

- Social signin buttons are type submit in a form with an action of /Account/ExternalLogin
- ExternalLogin returns a redirect for browser to go to Google and request authorization to connect
- If ok Google returns back to the ReturnUrl provided
- Microsoft Owin middleware intercepts this return to /domain/signin-google, authenticates the user and calls ExternalLoginCallback

Our system fails on the return to /domain/signin-google with a 404 error. LinkedIn and Facebook work fine, and ironically the system works perfectly fine on our development server logging in with google.

Nuget is up to date - we are running on v4.0 Owin libraries. We upgraded last week which could be a pointer to an issue, but we have reverted back to 3.1 and the issue remains.

There have been no changes to the Gateway or IIS settings in months. There is a URL rewrite on the domain to get rid of the www part of the server address, but again this hasn't been touched for about a year.

Our Startup.Auth file looks like this:

```
Partial Public Class Startup
    Public Sub ConfigureAuth(app As IAppBuilder)
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(AddressOf ApplicationDbContext.Create)
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(Of ApplicationUserManager)(AddressOf ApplicationUserManager.Create)
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(Of ApplicationSignInManager)(AddressOf ApplicationSignInManager.Create)
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(New CookieAuthenticationOptions() With {
            .AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            .Provider = New CookieAuthenticationProvider() With {
                .OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity(Of ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser)(
                    validateInterval:=TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                    regenerateIdentity:=Function(manager, user) user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))},
            .LoginPath = New PathString("/Account/Login")})
        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie)
        app.UseTwoFactorSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorCookie, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5))
        app.UseTwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie)

        Dim facebookOptions = New FacebookAuthenticationOptions With {
            .AppId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("FacebookClientID"),
            .AppSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("FacebookClientSecret"),
            .Provider = New FacebookAuthenticationProvider With {
                .OnAuthenticated = Function(context)
                                       context.Identity.AddClaim(New Claim("Provider", "Facebook"))
                                       context.Identity.AddClaim(New Claim("provider:name", context.Identity.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Name)))
                                       context.Identity.AddClaim(New Claim("provider:accesstoken", context.AccessToken, ClaimValueTypes.String, "Facebook"))
                                       context.Identity.AddClaim(New Claim("provider:picture", String.Format("//graph.facebook.com/{0}/picture?type=square", context.User.Value(Of String)("id"))))
                                       Dim email = context.Identity.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email)
                                       If email IsNot Nothing Then
                                           context.Identity.AddClaim(New Claim("provider:email", email))
                                       Else
                                           Dim fb = New Facebook.FacebookClient(context.AccessToken)
                                           Dim myInfo = fb.Get("/me?fields=email")
                                           email = myInfo("email")
                                           If email IsNot Nothing Then
                                               context.Identity.AddClaim(New Claim("provider:email", email))
                                           Else
                                               Throw New ArgumentNullException("myInfo.Email")
                                           End If
                                       End If

                                       Return Task.FromResult(0)
                                   End Function}}
        facebookOptions.Scope.Add("email")
        app.UseFacebookAuthentication(facebookOptions)

        app.UseGoogleAuthentication(New GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions() With {
           .ClientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("GoogleClientID"),
           .ClientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("GoogleClientSecret"),
           .Provider = New GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationProvider With {.OnAuthenticated = Function(context)
                                                                                           context.Identity.AddClaim(New Claim("Provider", "Google"))
                                                                                           context.Identity.AddClaim(New Claim("provider:name", context.Identity.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Name)))
                                                                                           context.Identity.AddClaim(New Claim("provider:email", context.Identity.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email)))
                                                                                           context.Identity.AddClaim(New Claim("provider:accesstoken", context.AccessToken, ClaimValueTypes.String, "Google"))
                                                                                           context.Identity.AddClaim(New Claim("provider:picture", context.User.SelectToken("image")?.Value(Of String)("url")))

                                                                                           Return Task.FromResult(0)
                                                                                       End Function}})

        app.UseLinkedInAuthentication(New LinkedInAuthenticationOptions With {
            .ClientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("LinkedInClientID"),
            .ClientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("LinkedInClientSecret"),
            .Provider = New LinkedInAuthenticationProvider With {.OnAuthenticated = Function(context)
                                                                                        context.Identity.AddClaim(New Claim("Provider", "LinkedIn"))
                                                                                        context.Identity.AddClaim(New Claim("provider:name", context.Name))
                                                                                        context.Identity.AddClaim(New Claim("provider:email", context.Email))
                                                                                        context.Identity.AddClaim(New Claim("provider:accesstoken", context.AccessToken, ClaimValueTypes.String, "LinkedIn"))
                                                                                        context.Identity.AddClaim(New Claim("provider:picture", context.User.SelectToken("pictureUrl").ToString))

                                                                                        Return Task.FromResult(0)
                                                                                    End Function}})

        app.MapSignalR
        GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.Register(GetType(IUserIdProvider), Function() New MySignalRIdProvider())
    End Sub
End Class
```

We're out of ideas - any thoughts gratefully received!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the answer - we had 1 url rewrite rule on the site that hadn't been updated for about a year that when disabled allowed us to authenticate using Google.

Our development environment worked because it had a slightly more foolproof version of the rules (again that have been present for 9 months) that we have since put into live.

Here's the url rewrite xml if anybody needs an example:

```
<rules>
  <rule name="Remove WWW" enabled="false" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="*" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
            <add input="{CACHE_URL}" pattern="*://www.*" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}//{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
  </rule>
    <rule name="Enforce https" enabled="true" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="https://investorsedge.net:8443/{R:1}" />
    </rule>
<rule name="Remove WWW and Ensure HTTPS" enabled="false" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.)" />
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://investorsedge.net/{R:0}:8443" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" />
                </rule>
<rule name="Remove www rule 2" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="true" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.(.+)$" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://{C:1}/{R:0}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
</rules>
```